# How to get Chrome and Safari to accept query strings on blobs?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, blob, query-string

I've been doing some testing with creating blobs and referencing them for user generated scripts because it makes debugging a lot easier, but I've recently found that while this solution has been very helpful in Firefox, it does not work in Chrome or Safari.

```js
function includeScript(withQuery, script) {

  var file = new Blob([script], {
    type: "text/javascript"
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);

  if (withQuery == true)
    url += "?test=hi";

  var addMe = document.createElement("script");
  addMe.src = url;
  addMe.type = "text/javascript";

  document.head.appendChild(addMe);
}

function tryIt(withQuery) {
  includeScript(withQuery, "alert('hey');");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="tryIt(false)">Try It Without Query</button>
<button onclick="tryIt(true)">Try It With Query</button>
```

How can I get blobs to work with query strings in Safari and Chrome the same way they do in Firefox?